# MS Access VBA Add Decimals to Output

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have data which have 2 decimal places (See Figure)[image] and am using the function to subtract the two values but I'm getting a rounded number as my output.  I've tried to add float to the following expression "(L.M123_Corr_Integrator-R.M123_Corr_Integrator)" but it's throwing out an error.  I'm not familiar with sql/vba code so any useful information would help.

`sql = "UPDATE (SELECT R.DateLog , ( L.M123_Corr_Integrator - R.M123_Corr_Integrator) AS Gross " & _
      "FROM   tbl_M123_DataSet AS L  INNER JOIN tbl_M123_DataSet AS R " & _
      "ON L.DateLog = DATEADD('d', 1, R.DateLog)) as T " & _
      "INNER JOIN tbl_M123_DataSet ON tbl_M123_DataSet.DateLog = T.DateLog " & _
      "Set Gross_kWh = Gross"
dbs.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
MsgBox dbs.RecordsAffected & " rows affected on column GrossKW"`

That query unobfuscated looks like this:

```
UPDATE
   (
      SELECT
         R.DateLog,
         L.M123_Corr_Integrator - R.M123_Corr_Integrator AS Gross
      FROM
         tbl_M123_DataSet AS L
         INNER JOIN tbl_M123_DataSet AS R
            ON L.DateLog = DATEADD('d', 1, R.DateLog)
   ) AS T
   INNER JOIN tbl_M123_DataSet
      ON tbl_M123_DataSet.DateLog = T.DateLog
SET Gross_kWh = Gross
```

Comment: What data type is column `Gross_kWh`? (And what table is it in? Please use aliases consistently.)

Comment: Gross_kWh is a "Number" data type.  Tried to format this from the table with 2 decimal places but the output was still a whole number with two zeros after the decimal place.

Comment: This is in tbl_M123_DataSet @ErikE

Comment: @cronos2546 Sorry I'm not familiar with VBA or SQL syntax so I just tried a number of things for the expression.  I added "$d" or even just "float" after the arithmetic expression above.  I got errors indicating that the syntax was incorrect and wasn't able to run the code.

Comment: Please provide an example. Your words are inconsistent. What are some of the input and output numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you have the table field `Gross_kWh` set to integer. In the table design view, highlight the row `Gross_kWh` and set its number type to 'Double'.

Also be aware that Access will sometimes round numbers for display, but the decimal accurate number is stored in the table correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to set the text format to a display the decimal value, but I didn't look at the table properties.

Comment: This is exactly what I was getting at when I asked "What data type is column `Gross_kWh`"?